# Unconstrained optimization - parameters' values for global maximum

Tags: optimization, hessian-matrix

Consider the following function

$f(x,y)=p \cdot x^a \cdot y^b - w_xx-w_yy$

with $(p,x,y,w_x,w_y) \in \mathbb{R^5_+} $ (this is because $f(x,y)$ is a profit function)

(a) Solve the first-order conditions in order to find $(x,y)$ that maximizes $f(x,y)$.

Here's my answer (it's a bit long, so I'll skip some steps).

$$\begin{cases} f_x = 0 \therefore p \cdot a \cdot x^{a-1} \cdot y^b = w_x \,\, \dots I \\ f_y = 0 \therefore p \cdot b \cdot x^a \cdot y^{b-1} = w_y \,\, \dots II\end{cases}$$

Since $x \neq 0, y \neq 0$, we can divide the equations and get:
$$ \frac{a}{b} \cdot x^{-1} \cdot y = \frac{w_x}{w_y} \therefore y = \frac{b}{a} \cdot \frac{w_x}{w_y} \cdot x \,\, \dots III$$

Substituting back in equation (I), we find:

$$ \large{x^* = \left( \frac{1}{p} \cdot a^{b-1} \cdot b^{-b} \cdot w_2^b \cdot w_1^{1-b} \right)^\frac{1}{a+b-1}}$$

and

$$ \large{y^* = \frac{b}{a} \cdot \frac{w_1}{w_2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{p} \cdot a^{b-1} \cdot b^{-b} \cdot w_2^b \cdot w_1^{1-b} \right)^\frac{1}{a+b-1} }$$

(b) Use the second-order conditions to determine the parameters' $a,b,p,w_x,w_y$ values such that the solution for the optimization problem is a global maximum.

The Hessian will be:

$$ H_{f(x,y)}= \begin{bmatrix} p \cdot a \cdot (a-1) \cdot x^{a-2} \cdot y^b & p \cdot a \cdot b \cdot x^{a-1} \cdot y^{b-1} \\ p \cdot a \cdot b \cdot x^{a-1} \cdot y^{b-1} & p \cdot b \cdot (b-1) \cdot x^a \cdot y^{b-2}\end{bmatrix} $$

In order for $f(x,y)$ to be strictly concave, $|H_2| < 0, |H| > 0$ where $H_2$ is the sub-matrix of $H$ that is found by removing the second column and second row.

For $|H|$, we have:

$$ |H| = p^2 \cdot a \cdot (a-1) \cdot b \cdot (b-1) \cdot (x^{a-1})^2 \cdot (y^{b-1})^2 - p^2\cdot a^2 \cdot b^2 \cdot (x^{a-1})^2 \cdot (y^{b-1})^2 \therefore \\\\ |H| = p^2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot (x^{a-1})^2 \cdot (y^{b-1})^2 \cdot [ (a-1) \cdot (b-1)-ab ]$$

Now if we make $p^2 \cdot (x^{a-1})^2 \cdot (y^{b-1})^2 = k > 0$, all we have to worry about is:

$a \cdot b \cdot [(a-1)(b-1) -ab] = ab \cdot [ab - a -b + 1 - ab] = ab \cdot (1-a-b)$

So our first inequality is $ab \cdot (1-a-b) > 0$.

Now, substituting our optimal values into $|H_2|$ we have:

$|H_2(x^*,y^*)| = p \cdot a \cdot (a-1) \cdot \left( \left( \frac{1}{p} \cdot a^{b-1} \cdot b^{-b} \cdot w_2^b \cdot w_1^{1-b} \right)^\frac{1}{a+b-1} \right)^{a-2} \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \cdot \frac{w_1}{w_2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{p} \cdot a^{b-1} \cdot b^{-b} \cdot w_2^b \cdot w_1^{1-b} \right)^\frac{1}{a+b-1} \right)^b \\\\ \therefore |H_2(x^*,y^*)| = p \cdot a \cdot (a-1) \cdot \left( \frac{b}{a} \cdot \frac{w_x}{w_y} \right)^b \cdot \left( \frac{1}{p} \cdot a^{b-1} \cdot b^{-b} \cdot w_y^b \cdot w_x^{1-b}\right)^{\frac{a+b-2}{a+b-1}} $

Now since $p > 0, w_x > 0, w_y > 0$, I'll remove them from the equation to declutter it a bit and I'll also drop the $(x^*,y^*)$.

$$ \large{|H_2| = a \cdot (a-1) \cdot b^{-b} \cdot a^{-b} \cdot a^{\frac{(b-1)(a+b-2)}{a+b-1}} \cdot b^{\frac{b \cdot (a+b-2)}{a+b-1}} \therefore \\ |H_2| = (a-1) \cdot a^{\frac{(1-b)(a+b-1) + (b-1)(a+b-2)}{a+b-1}} \cdot b^{\frac{-b(a+b-1) + b(a+b+2)}{a+b-1}} \therefore \\ |H_2| = (a-1) \cdot a^{\frac{1-b}{a+b-1}} \cdot b^{\frac{3b}{a+b-1}} \therefore \\\\ |H_2| = (a-1) \cdot a^{\frac{1-b}{a+b-1}} \cdot b^{\frac{b}{a+b-1}} \cdot \left( b^{\frac{b}{a+b-1}} \right)^2}$$

Now, because the last term is always positive, all we need is:

$$ \large{(a-1) \cdot a^{\frac{1-b}{a+b-1}} \cdot b^{\frac{b}{a+b-1}} < 0 } $$

Without imposing further restrictions I have no idea how to continue. If we impose $a>0,b>0$, than our problem can be reduced to

$$ \begin{cases} -a-b+1 >0 \\ (a-1) \cdot a < 0 \end{cases} $$

and our final solution is $$ \boxed{\boxed{0 < a < 1, \\ 0 < b < 1-a, \\(p,w_x,w_y) \in \mathbb{R_+^3} }} $$

Is my solution correct? Did I miss something that would make the calculations simpler or at least feasible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After receiving answers to your question, it is a good idea to respond or to accept the given answers. Thanks.

Comment: I'm so sorry, @Ahmad. A *lot* happened since then and I was not able to look at your answer and give a proper commentary. I'll do it now.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, you only need the hessian to be negative semidefinite everywhere and strictly negative definite at the candidate point found from the first part. This means that you have a concave function with only one local maximum, that is, this local minimum is unique in a small neighborhood. Thus, it is the unique global maximum of the function due to its concavity.
Also, the determinant of the symmetric matrix $H$ must be nonpositive as a necessary condition for negative semidefiniteness.

Comment: The determinant of H must be nonnegative, right? A is negative semidefinite if and only if its kth order principal minors are nonpositive for k odd and nonnegative for k even (https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/qfs/t) . Or are you refering to $H_2$?

Comment: Wrong! For H being negative semidefinite, a necessary condition is to have a nonpositive determinant.  But, in general, a Hermitian matrix H is PSD/PD iff -H is NSD/ND. For the results regarding PSD: a Hermitian matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all of its principal minors are nonnegative. For being PD: a Hermitian matrix is positive definite if and only if all of its leading principal minors are nonnegative.

Comment: I am definitely not following you. Every source I have says the same: for convexity or positive semidefiniteness, all principal minors must be nonnegative. For concavity or negative semidefiniteness, all principal minors of odd order must be nonpositive and all principal minors of even order must be nonnegative. As you can see here: https://imgur.com/a/RIrYR9Y

Comment: Sorr, you’re right. I also found it here: https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat419/lecture3.pdf.